# Configuring Maven Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration

I am having issues in building maven project using m2e.

When I run update project/clean project usually maven runs

> mvn clean install

But I need to modify this to

> mvn clean install -Penv-itt

or

> mvn clean install -Penv-uat

and so on. I need to pass these parameters otherwise build will not success.

But how do I modify settings in Eclipse (m2e plugin) to create multiple profiles or atleast 
I can add them dynamically

Eclipse Juno SR1.
M2E updated version as per Market

Comment: Isn't there a single set of profiles you use during development? In that case you could activate them by default.

Comment: We do change from dev to itt to uat and to prod frequently. Atleast I want to run for single profile. then i can change to environment whenever I want by modifying it. Can you please tell me step by step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to create two different profiles and run them as needed

[image]

and then in the new window..fill in the command as below

[image]
fill the details and click apply button

[image: fill the details and click apply button]

repeat the above process for uat profile and fill in the configuration as below and click apply button

[image: repeat the above process for uat profile and fill in the configuration as below and click apply button]

follow the below steps to run the created profiles as needed
[image]

[image]